# Is there a way in AngularJS to convert a model similar to this Jquery method?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

A previous developer was serializing form data this way using Jquery:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#form').serializeArray()))
```

That produces a result that looks like this:

```
 [
  {"name":"FirstName","value":"Roger"},
  {"name":"LastName","value":"Daughtry"},
  {"name":"SS__c","value":"123-45-6789"},
  {"name":"Birthdate","value":"05/05/2013"},
  {"name":"POB","value":"Portugal"},
  {"name":"Citizenship","value":"US"}
 ]
```

Is there a simple way to convert a $scope.Model object in AngularJS to this same string format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = [];
angular.forEach($scope.Model, function(val, key){
  result.push({ name: key, value: val });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using 2 existing Angular methods in 1 line:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Qper/1/

```
function x($scope) {
    $scope.Model = {};
    $scope.Model.a = 'asdf';
    $scope.Model.b = 'asdffff';
    $scope.Model.c = true;

    console.log(angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($scope.Model)));
}
```

Edit: Your question says "string format", but your code example uses JSON.parse which will give you back an object.  If you want the object, then just use `$scope.Model`, if you want the string (depending on what you need to do with it), you can either just use `angular.toJson($scope.Model)` which will get you the string in code, or in your HTML you can {{ Model | json }} which will print out the model in your markup (so you could wrap a `textarea` around it):

http://jsfiddle.net/9Qper/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the model beforehand:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="Model.field1">
  <input type="text" ng-model="Model.field2">
  <input type="text" ng-model="Model.field3">
</form>
```

Will yield into an object. `scope.Model`.

**EDIT:** In case you do not know the model name but have the names of the properties somewhere, you could work around this in a similar fashion:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Model[field]" ng-repeat="field in NameOfFields">
```

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrQ77/) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Hippo. I don't know the model, unfortunately.

Comment: added some hints for unknown fields.